# How to create UIImageVIew in custom UITableViewCell? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController`, and 1 prototype cell which is defined in my own custom cell class. I have a `UIImageView` in the top right corner, with top and trailing margin constraints, as well as a fixed width and height:

[In Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLG0y.png)

The problem is, when I run the program, the `TableView` is created but the `imageView` is oversized:

[At runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kY5g.png)

After researching some similar questions on this site, I've come to the conclusion that:

> The cell's imageView only appears and is sized when you assign an
>   image to it.

I've already tried the following code in the custom cell class, and the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
cell.imageView?.frame = CGRectMake(300, 52, 292, 136)
cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
cell.contentView.addSubview(cell.imageView!)
```

Am I missing something or what do I do to get the `imageView` to the size I've made its constraints for?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes you need to add constrains in cell's contains view and no need to set frame of imageView programatically.
For examples: http://postimg.org/image/utqzbrjn1/

Comment: Could you give a screenshot of your tableviewCell in the storyboard? It helps if you show us your constraints. Ad would be nice to show your complete code under `cellForRowAtIndexPath` too.

Answer (score 1):

UIView has the attribute contentMode - try to define it as ScaleToFill:

```
self.someImage.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help everyone!

I made a stupid mistake by referencing the custom cell's generic `imageView?`, rather than the `IB Outlet` I made under a different name.

Wrong:

```
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "whatever name")
```

Right:

```
cell.dogImageView.image = UIImage(named: "labrador")
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, what values are the fixed width and height constraints? It's hard to tell the difference between the interface builder and the device screenshots as the size of the view controller is different.

My suggestion would be doing away with the fixed width and height constraints, and instead:

•  Pin the bottom of the image view to the bottom of the cell - this gives the image view it's height.

• Add an aspect ratio constraint to the image view - this gives the image view it's width, based on it's height.

This means that even if you end up changing the height of your cells, your image view will always fit inside of the cell.

Kudos for using prototype cells and a UITableViewCell subclass though - I agree with this method completely!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Matthew! I've tried your suggestions but it's giving me the same results. The width is 292 and the height is 136. I should have mentioned the device is an iPhone 6. The imageView is the only issue and it seems to be because its constraints are not being applied.

Comment: Can you possibly provide more code around the setup of the table view itself, as well as the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method? Then we might be able to see if you're doing something you shouldn't, or forgetting to do something you should be doing!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems vague although I agree with you using the custom cell class. What this does is to attempt to download all images set and if unable to download, it will replace the image with an image placeholder saved on the assets. All images have the same sizes when loaded.

Here is what you can do to make it work. Here is your custom class.

```
class SomeCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imgMain: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblMain: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        imgMain.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        imgMain.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func configureCell(image: UIImage, text: String){
        imgMain.image = image
        lblMain.text = text
    }

}
```

Then on your ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var somePics = ["http://www.something.com/pic1.jpg","http://www.something.net/pic2.jpg","http://www.something.com/pic3.jpg","http://www.something.com/pic4.jpg","http://www.something.net/pic5.jpg"]

    var someTitles = ["Picture 1", "Picture 2", "Picture 3", "Picture 4", "Picture 5"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SomeCell") as? SomeCell {

            var img: UIImage!

            let url = NSURL(string: somePics[indexPath.row])!

            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                img = UIImage(data: data)
            }else {
                img = UIImage(named: "somePlaceholderpic")
            }

            cell.configureCell(img, text: someTitles[indexPath.row])

            return cell

        } else {

            return SomeCell()

        }
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return somePics.count
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Hope this helps. :)